# How to get values of <select> tag and radio tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am having trouble in getting the values of my select tags and radio tags in my html project. I would like the values to be accessed by the javascript function but it seems that it goes to the wrong servlet.

Here is my current code:

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Pick Month</b></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="Month" id="Month">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Year</b></td>
            <td>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Year" id="Year">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</center><br>
<button onclick="GenerateSoC()">Generate Statement of Cash Flows</button>
```

Javascript

```
function GenerateSoC()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("Month");
    var year = document.getElementById("Year");
    var month = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if(month === 1 || month === 3 ||month === 5 ||month === 7 ||month === 8 ||month === 10 ||month === 12)
    {
        document.getElementById("myform").action="Accounting_SoC_MonthlySoC";
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
    else if(month === 4 || month === 6 || month === 9 || month === 11)
    {
        document.getElementById("myform").action="Accounting_SoC_MonthlySoC30";
        document.getElementById("myform").submit();
    }
    else
    {
        if((year % 400 === 0) || ((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)))
        {
            document.getElementById("myform").action="Accounting_SoC_MonthlyFeb";
            document.getElementById("myform").submit(); 
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("myform").action="Accounting_SoC_MonthlyFeb28";
            document.getElementById("myform").submit(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still quite new in using javascript so I'm not really fond of using it. Is there a problem with my javascript function? I copied a few of the lines on this site but it redirects to a different servlet and not the correct servlet! Thanks in advance for answering!

Answer (score 2):

The value you are getting into the month variable is a string, you are trying to compare it to integers with "===" (equal value and equal type operator), in order to do that you need to cast the selected value to integer before comparing:

```
var month = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value, 10);
```

This way your value will be casted to integer in base 10 and you will be able to compare it to integers.

Comment: You don't need to use parseInt, you can use "==" (equal value but not necessarily equal type) instead of "==="

Comment: Yes you can but I prefer to have one point where I cast the data instead of many places where I treat the data in less safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line

```
var year = document.getElementById("Year");
```

You need to get the value by `.value` as

```
var month = document.getElementById("Year").value
```